# Is it important more people participate on Meta.P.SE?

Tags: discussion

One problem arise on my mind. We start to get useful and good discussions here in Meta, but "half dozen" users are deciding important issues. Do you agree?

How to bring more users to real participation?

Comment: I would also love to see more people participate here, besides mentioning the meta were appropriate and drawing more people to the site itself there is nothing we can do... Drawing people to the meta itself will draw in the wrong people I guess.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is "yes" it is important that people participate on a site's meta - but they don't have to do it all the time.

The more complex answer is that with the proliferation of sites, I (and I expect others who are active on several sites) just don't have the time to participate on any site's meta as much as I'd like to and indeed should. I try to get on each site's meta once a day to check to see which questions are currently active, but there's often nothing more I can add.

As to how to bring more users - I don't know. If there was more controversy then people would come here to ask why their post was closed/edited/whatever, but I'm not convinced that's what we really want.

The top meta questions are already featured on the right side bar when viewing questions on the main site.

Comment: I saw you participating actively in most sites :-)

Comment: @bigown - I meant on meta.

Comment: I know.

Comment: It's so true, there are so many sites right now, it's really hard to get and stay involved in all of them.

Answer (score 3):

There are some crucial questions begin asked which will afect who participates on P.SE in the future and to what extent. The key one seems to be [Are questions not directly related to programming (but might concern programmers) on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/dealing-with-what-are-some-good-types-of-pickles-for-programmers-type-question) . I can well imaging people not visiting if those questions continue to be allowed, and vice versa. We could do with more people who use the site expressing their views.