# Are Career-Advice Questions On-Topic Here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, faq-proposed

I have a question about

- Education,
- Finding a job,
- Hiring,
- Interviews,
- Job Titles
- Training Materials,
- Classes,
- Certifications,
- Skill sets,
- Marketing,
- Job Stress,
- Workplace Interaction,
- Business Development,
- General Management,
- Coaching,
- Attitude Adjustment, Convincing My Boss/Coworker, etc.

Are any of these subjects on-topic here?

Comment: see also: [Why was my question closed or down voted?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/)

Answer (score 10):

### No.

Software Engineering is a site for asking questions *directly related* to the [Systems Development Life Cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA9UR.jpg) (but not code troubleshooting or writing specific code).

Questions seeking career or education advice are off topic. They are only meaningful to the asker and do not generate lasting value for the broader programming community. Furthermore, in most cases, any answer is going to be a subjective opinion that may not take into account all the nuances of a (your) particular circumstance.

Comment: Also, I recommend [chat] as a good place for these.