# Where to ask questions about how to write a job application?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, site-rec

I have some special questions about 'job applications' for a software engineering job.

Is this the right place to ask something about writing a job application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Career-Advice Questions On-Topic Here?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8206/are-career-advice-questions-on-topic-here)

Comment: see also: [Are you still confused about what Programmers (now called Software Engineering) is for?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5654/31260)

Answer (score 5):

This site is intended for questions that fit within the field of software engineering, in particular software engineering concepts and design-level questions.

This site is not intended for questions about the life of programmers. A question does not become on topic just because it is specific to software engineers, that's part of why this site was renamed from "Programmers" (people) to "Software Engineering" (topic).

Career advice is explicitly off topic, see also: [Why was my question closed as "Off Topic - Career or Educational Advice?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6488/)
For some questions about job applications, *The Workplace* site can sometimes be a suitable place, but [check their on-topic guidelines first](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

However, many valid and good questions are simply not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model, for example if you are interested in advice for your personal circumstances, if you want a discussion, or if you are interested in hearing different experiences. Reddit might be a good place to check instead, but check the rules of the subreddit before posting.